# Java - Can't find error in class definition

Tags: java, logic

I have a problem with the following Code. It was an exam task and I couldn't figure out what the error in the given Code was. We should find the error in the class A which would prevent us from testing the Code with JUnit.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A {

private List<String> s;

    public A() {
        s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("Bob");
        s.add("Alice");
        s.add("Eve");
    }

    public String s(B b){
        int t = b.t();
        String r = "Hello ";
        for (String z : s) {
            boolean x = b.f(t, 5);
            if (x) {
                r = r + z;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    // main added by myself for testing purpose
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A test = new A();
        test.s();
    }
}

interface B{
int t();//complex calculus

boolean f(int a, int b); // complex algorithm
}
```

I assume, that the error has something to do with:

1. method `s(B b)` having the same name as the attribute `s` or
2. `interface B` not being implemented

Thanks a lot in advance for help!

Comment: What prevents you from testing that code is that it doesn't compile. Why don't you just try compiling the code by yourself (just copy and paste it into your IDE)?

Comment: I am assuming something wrong in follwing: 1) calling `s(B b)` without parameter in `main()` but decalred as parameterized method.   2)  interface should be implemented and it's methods should be overriden before use.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that it doesn't compile, because of the `test.s()` , what I was trying to figure out is, what do I have to change so it **could** compile. I also know that i have to paramterize the `test.s()`, but what do i have to put in particularly to be working. Sorry for missleading there, should have commentated it out.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen 1)  Said it already to JB. 2) Could you give me a small code snippet, how a overriden method looks like? I'm a bit irritated right now. That would be great!

Comment: Remove the main method, and it will compile. I don't see any reason why you couldn't unit-test A. What is your **actual** question? Have you tried writing a unit test for A?

Comment: @JBNizet I know, i could just remove the main method. The first exam question to this, just was _Find a error in A, which hindrance you from testing._ , so i actually don't know what to say more. The second question was _How would you solve the described error without changing the functionality of the code_.

Comment: My answer would be: "there is no specification (i.e. javadoc) whatsoever in the code, so it's possible to know what the code does, but not what it is *supposed* to do. Since a unit test must test that code does what it is *supposed* to do, writing an effective unit test is impossible.". If the code was properly documented and specified what it's supposed to do, then unit-testing that code wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Seems reasonably to me. Thanks @JBNizet for taking the time to answering me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this code for reference:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class A implements B{

private List<String> s;

public A() {
    s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("Bob");
    s.add("Alice");
    s.add("Eve");
}
//overridden method from interface B
public int t(){
  //what you want this method to do
}
//overridden method from interface B
public boolean f(int a, int b){
  //what you want this method to do
}
public String s(){ 
    A test = new A();
    int t = test.t(); 
    String r = "Hello ";
    for (String z : s) {
        boolean x = test.f(t, 5);
        if (x) {
            r = r + z;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// main added by myself for testing purpose
public static void main(String[] args){
    A test = new A();
    System.out.println(test.s()); //printing the result of `test.s()`
}
}
interface B{
  int t();//complex calculus
  boolean f(int a, int b); // complex algorithm
}
```

You can refer to this link for further understanding.

Source: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interfaces-in-java/